# I have two env files in my project. But nestjs load the first env file only

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nestjs, development-environment, production-environment

I have two env files in my project. But nestjs load the first env file only.  Any idea about this?

My app.module file:

[image]

The script that I used to run different env files in my project:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

That's because the result when you specify many env files is equivalent to use an spread of the properties in reverse order, it means all the properties in the first env file will take precedence.

it is explained here at the docs:
[Nest js config](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-env-file-path)

The option becomes useful if you want to spread your configuration in multiple files but they are all related to the same environment.

**Solution**

If your goal is to be able to run multiple environments I have to say this is a bit tricky with NestJs.

When you use `cross-env NODE_ENV=development` you are setting `process.env.NODE_ENV` equal to `development` and thats all, NestJs is not smart enough to know and doesn't have any file replacement strategy like the one used by Angular for example to know if it should use one file or another.

You can choose which file to use by using something like:

```
envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
```

or

```
envFilePath: `${process.cwd()}/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
```

You can modify the paths to match the location of your env files, `process.cwd()` points to the root of the project and for this example to work it means the files named development.env and production.env exists at the root of the project.

This way the configuration prepared for dependency injection will depend on the NODE_ENV value.